# How to set base class per instance of derived class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, inheritance, iterable

It's happened to me many times where I encounter a problem, and the solution is very often a circular list. For example:

```py
my_list = CircularList([1,2,3,4])
my_list[0] # 1
my_list[4] # 1
```

And to implement such a construct I did this:

```py
class CircularList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index: int):
        return list.__getitem__(self, index % len(self))
```

After implementing that class I wanted to make a single class that could "*Circularize*" any iterable object that implements `__getitem__` and `__len___`, while still keeping all the attributes and methods of that object.
So for example:

```py
circ_iter = Circular(MyIter(1,2,3,4))   # Object keeps MyIters's attributes
circ_tuple = Ciruclar((1,2,3,4))  # Still has attributes of a tuple
```

The Problem I ran into is that I couldn't find a way to dynamically set the base class for each instance based on the type of the parameter.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: out of pure curiosity -- what use case would require this as opposed to `collections.deque`?

Comment: @TeejayBruno I'm looking for something that would support this sort of code:
`deq = deque([1,2,3,4])`
`print(deq[4])`
`
`deque` in this case raises an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with multiple inheritance via a mix-in class, though you have to ensure two things:

1. No other class overriding `__getitem__` appears *before* `Circularize` in the list of base classes
2. Your own class does not override `__getitem__`.

(Technically, you just can't override `__getitem__` in a way that prevents `Circularize.__getitem__` from working as intended. But that gets into the issue of how inheritance conflicts with composability, and not really within the scope of this answer.)

```
class Circularize:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return super().__getitem__(index % len(self))


_circular_types = {}
def Circular(v: collections.abc.Sequence):
    t = type(v)
    tname = t.__name__
    if tname not in _circular_types:
        _circular_types[tname] = type(f'Circular{tname.upper()}', (Circularize, t), {})

    return _circular_types[tname](v)
    

circ_list = Circular([1,2,3])  # Creates an instance of CircularList
circ_tuple = Circular((1,2,3))  # Creates an instance of CircularTuple
```

I'm omitting `CircularSet` because sets themselves are not indexible (i.e., `set` is not a subclass of `Sequence`). If you want to iterate over the elements of a set repeatedly, use `itertools.cycle({1,2,3})` (which yields 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, ...).

Comment: That does not really solve the problem though. OP's intention is to have a "generic" `Circular` class which can be used to make an iterable object of any kind "circular", e.g. `list`, `tuple`, `set`.

Comment: But what if I imported a library that added say, ten new iterable objects. I'm looking for a solution where I wouldn't have to declare a new class for each of them even if its only two lines.

Comment: Yeah, I was working on fixing it, but I'm not sure this is a good approach. (I could use `Circularize` to create a new class on the fly, based on the type of argument passed to `Circular`, and keep a cache so that I don't recreate the same class over and over again.)

Comment: Updated; it's at least closer to what you originally asked for.

Comment: @chepner I really like this solution thank you!

Comment: I deleted my answer as I realized I ended up with the same solution as you. I wasn't aware that built-ins like `__len__` don't respect the hack with `__getattribute__`

Comment: I still would maybe enhance the typing by doing a cast to a generic input `TypeVar("_Container", bound=Sequence)` .

Comment: @flakes I didn't dislike your answer; composition is definitely preferable over inheritance when possible. Something about your definition of `__getattribute__` bothered me, but I could never quite put my finger on what. (I didn't have a chance to test it much.) I think it could be fixed to make the approach work properly. (I think having the new value still be considered an instance of the original type is important, but that's relatively easy to fix using things like `abc.register`.)

Comment: Hmm, well if you do end up playing around with it, the part that stumped me was when doing: `len(circular([]))` with: "TypeError: object of type 'CircularWrapper' has no len()" I tried to debug it, but I read that some builtins will cache the method on the class rather than always go to the instance for the implementation.